# How to enable TextColor & FontSize selection option in WYSIWYG editor for web content in liferay DXP

Tags: liferay-7, web-content

I am having a html field in web content in liferay 7. i am using liferay default WYSIWYG editor. I want to allow user to change the text color and background.

Let me know if anyone has idea to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default inline editor is the AlloyEditor. The dev documentation can be found here https://alloyeditor.com/docs/develop/. There are examples of how to add new control elements.

Another possibility is to switch Liferay to use the old CK editor that was in the previous versions.

Comment: Hi Miroslav, thanks!!  i have a explore the alloyeditor api docs and we have a decided to switch back to old CK Editor, can you tell me how to enable CK Editor in liferay 7?

Answer (score 3):

I found the configuration to enable the old CKEditor in liferay 7, This might help someone so i am answering my own question. Add below properties in portal-properties file and restart the server.

```
editor.wysiwyg.default=ckeditor
editor.wysiwyg.portal-impl.portlet.ddm.text_html.ftl=ckeditor
```